# Change the dot after a listing to clip

Tags: css

I have a common listing

```
 ul.dsgvo {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

But I want to change the dot after the listing to ")"

current: a.
goal: a)

I already tried it with

```
content: counter(lower-alpha) ") ";
```

but this returned a 0 instead of lower-alpha (latin didnt work too)

list structure:

```
<ol><p>
    <li class="lawli">
    <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lawli">
    <p>text</p>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p>text</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <li class="lawli">
    <p>text</p>
    </li>
</p></ol>
```

[image: it should look like this.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `:before` and a counter  like so:

```css
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: listStyle;
}
li{
  counter-increment: listStyle;
}
li:before{
  content: counter(listStyle, lower-alpha) ") ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ol>
```

And with your HTML:

```css
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: lvl1;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol ol{
  counter-reset: lvl2
}
li{
  position: relative;
}
ol > li{
  counter-increment: lvl1;
}
ol > li > ul > li{
  counter-increment: lvl2;
}
li:before{
  content: counter(lvl1, lower-alpha) ") ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
}
li li:before{
  content: counter(lvl1, lower-alpha) counter(lvl2, lower-alpha) ") ";
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <p>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
    </li>
  </p>
</ol>
```

*But please remove the `p` right after the `ol`.*

And here is the code for the HTML for your provided image:

This Example uses two different counters. One for the first level (outer `ol`) named lvl1 and one for the given sublevel (called lvl2).

```css
ol{
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: lvl1;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol ol{
  counter-reset: lvl2
}
li{
  position: relative;
}
ol > li{
  counter-increment: lvl1;
}
ol > li > ul > li{
  counter-increment: lvl2;
}
li:before{
  content: "(" counter(lvl1) ") ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
}
li li:before{
  content: counter(lvl2, lower-alpha) ") ";
  left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <p>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>text</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <li class="lawli">
      <p>text</p>
    </li>
  </p>
</ol>
```

Comment: sadly this dont work for me.
I edited my post so you can see the li structure

Comment: What is not working? please show us what do you want to accomplish (lvl1 and lvl2)

Comment: my list is inside a <p> so when i use before my list gets outside my p and so the letter is in an other row. also if the text has two lines it starts under the letter and not not besides it.
A picture how it should look like is added

Comment: @shouyou17 I added two more snippets to my answer.

Comment: @YourBrainEatsYou Nice! But can you explain your last example, please? what means this line `counter-reset: lvl1;`?

Comment: @MaikLowrey it resets the counter named lvl1 back to 0. So when you add another list on your site it doesn't start at a weird index.

Answer (score 0):

Current CSS has added the `::marker` pseudo element for this. You can use it and create a fallback for browsers not supporting it (e.g. Safari):

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: listStyle;
}

li {
  counter-increment: listStyle;
}

@supports selector(::marker) {
  li::marker {
    content: counter(listStyle, lower-alpha) ") ";
  }
}

@supports not selector(::marker) {
  li::before {
    content: counter(listStyle, lower-alpha) ") ";
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
</ol>
```